# Dynamic block on the side suggestion

Tags: 7

Googling didn't help a lot in this issue. I was wondering if there is a drupal module that inserts sort of a dynamic content in the side of the page the can be expanded and shrinked while pressing a button/arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a Javascript question, no i don't think you will find that kind of module.

You can always write your own Javascript/jQuery [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) behavior (my suggestion) in a .js file in your theme, control any DOM element (like a block title) and assign this behavior to it.